# How can I get a list with the variable names of my xarray.Dataset?

Tags: python-xarray

I am looking for a way of extracting a list of the data variable names (strings) from a xarray.DataSet object.
I have used `xr_object.data_vars` and `xr_object.data_vars.keys()` but they don't seem to give anything usefull.

Also, the docs of xarray don't seem show that xarray has a built in method or attribute for getting something similar.

Anybody knows how to do so?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your question is a little ambigous. I guess you know that

```
xr_object.keys()
```

would give you a view of the dataset keys.

if you just need to put it to a list, then a list() function would do it ( at least after V0.11 ):
(ds is the xr_object)

```
list(ds.keys())
```

and if you need dimensions too:

```
list(ds.coords)
```

Comment: @Thomas that's not silly at all!  the result of the `.keys()` doesn't look like a list, I guess there is an internal api of xarray that is called to allow this to happen.    Also, please consider accept this as awnser if it solves your problem.

Comment: `list(xrds.data_vars)` also works

Comment: `list(ds)` seems to return the list of variables as well, it also works with data frames by the way `list(df)` returns the list of columns of a pandas data frame but I'm not sure if it's a recommended usage. I'll stick to `list(ds.data_vars)` for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I think there is the result you want.

```
#a list with the variable names of your xarray.Dataset
res = [i.name for i in xr_object.data_vars]
```

Comment: `[i for i in xr_object.data_vars]` also works